# Solr Is not indexing after DB upgrade

Tags: mysql, solr, lucene

```
<dataConfig>
  <dataSource type="JdbcDataSource" 
              driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
              url="jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1/hb" 
              user="root" password="jetech123"/>
<entity name="lmap" query="CALL get_locations(${location.region_id})">
        </entity>
<entity name="l1" query="SELECT IF((SELECT EXISTS(SELECT loc_name FROM lmap WHERE lvl = 1) AS loc_exist) = '0', NULL, (SELECT loc_name FROM lmap WHERE lvl = 1) ) l1">
            <field column="l1" name="l1"/>
            <entity name="l1_url" query="SELECT (SELECT CONCAT('/', LOWER(REPLACE(loc_name,' ','-'))) AS l1_url FROM lmap WHERE lvl = 1) l1_url">
                <field name="l1_url" column="l1_url"/>
            </entity>
        </entity>
```

In mysql 5.1 it is working fine and solr is also indexing properly, but when I upgrade my db to Mysql 5.5 solr is not indexing because of above entity. Can anyone please tell me what is the problem with the above entity?

Comment: NO error is showing in command prompt.

Comment: Have you checked catalina.log?